# preg_replace add space before and after of punctuation characters

Tags: php, regex, tokenize

I have a word filled with some punctuations.

```
$word = "'Ankara'da!?'";
```

I want to put spaces before or after punctuation characters.
Except apostrophe character which is in the middle of word.
At the result there must be only one space between letters or punctuations.

Required result: `' Ankara'da ! ? '`

I tried below and Added accent Turkish chars. ( because `\w` didnt work)

```
preg_replace('/(?![a-zA-Z0-9ğüışöçİĞÜŞÖÇ])/ig', " ", $word);
```

Result: `'Ankara 'da ! ? '`

Comment: Does it mean you need to have two spaces between `!` and `?` or one in the resulting string? If there is a space already before/after punctuation, should it be added?

Comment: yes, might be one space between punctations at result.

Comment: See my answer with 2 approaches.

Comment: @Yilmazerhakan: `might be one space between punctations at result` Is that an afterthought because this requirement is not part of your question.

Comment: @anubhava sorry, i asked wrong. it wasnt afterthought. in my required result you can see there is one space between punctuation.

Comment: thank you for your solution. sorry my english. if a punctuation between letters we also add left and right. if punctuation is near punctuation there is no need extra space between them of course. our gain is tokenization and i marked this in question tags. i was out and new came. so read your answer new.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to only add single spaces between punctuation symbols and avoid adding them at the start/end of the string, you may use the following solution:

```
$word = "'Ankara'da!?'";
echo trim(preg_replace_callback('~\b\'\b(*SKIP)(*F)|\s*(\p{P}+)\s*~u', function($m) {
    return ' ' . preg_replace('~\X(?=\X)~u', '$0 ', $m[1]) . ' ';
}, $word)); // => ' Ankara'da ! ? '
```

See [the PHP demo](https://ideone.com/7ZP6FW).

The `\b\'\b(*SKIP)(*F)` part matches and skips all `'` that are enclosed with word chars (letters, digits, underscores, and some more rarely used word chars). The `\s*(\p{P}+)\s*` part matches 0+ whitespaces, then captures 1+ punctuation symbols (including `_`!) into Group 1 and then any 0+ whitespaces are  matched. Then, single spaces are added after each Unicode character (`\X`) that is followed with another Unicode character (`(?=\X)`). The outer leading/trailing spaces are later removed with `trim()`).

There is a way to do that with

```
$word = "'Ankara'da!?'";
echo preg_replace('~^\s+|\s+$|(\s){2,}~u', '$1', 
    preg_replace('~(?!\b\'\b)\p{P}~u', ' $0 ', $word)
);
```

See [another PHP demo](https://ideone.com/ElsCXR)

The `'~(?!\b\'\b)\p{P}~u'` pattern matches any punctuation that is not `'` enclosed with word chars, and this symbol is enclosed with spaces, and then `'~^\s+|\s+$|(\s){2,}~u'` pattern is used to remove all whitespaces at the start/end of the string and shrinks all whitespaces into 1 in all other locations.

Comment: @Stribizew this is really what i want. I couldnt write completely required result and sorry. You completed my all question with my some missing anecdots with second demo. works like a charm.